# How to load a jQuery function only after the document finish loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Strange situation:

I am building a menu bar using `jQuery` and `CSS`.
In my JavaScript file, I have an `on-ready` function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    mark_active_menu();
}
```

and...

```
function mark_active_menu() {
    var elementWidth = $("nav li").width();
    alert(elementWidth);
}
```

For some reason, even BEFORE **all** the document finish loading, I'm getting the alert message with an incorrect width. Only when I release the message, the rest of the document loads and I'm getting the right width as it should be.

Why my function is being called BEFORE all the document finish loading?
Is there a way to load the function only AFTER a certain element done loading (Example: the `nav` element)?

Comment: Are you loading parts of your document with ajax?

Comment: You could hook into `$(window).on('resize', fn)` or `$(window).on('load', fn)`.

Comment: Also, the `ready()` method is not passed the eventObject, but rather the jQuery object itself.

Comment: Yes, I have few AJAX parts but they are not in my $(document)ready function

Comment: @BradM Well, the code is not using it, so we won't know if it was meant to be an event :)

Comment: @Lior It doesn't matter where they are. `$(document).ready` (and `$(window).load`) doesn't wait for dynamic content. You need to wait until all requests are done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [window.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload), it will be triggered after all the resource have completed loading.

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    mark_active_menu();
});
```

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading, [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The selector is `$("nav li")`...I don't see any images or frames...The problem is with AJAX loading the content.

Comment: @lan I do have AJAX in my code however none is being loaded with the document but only after the user trigger it

Comment: @Lior So if nothing is put on the page until **after** the user triggers it, how will `$(document).ready` execute at the right time? Anyways, `$(window).load` shouldn't make any difference for your problem for the same reason

Comment: @lan $(window).load solved my problem. I do think that you're right if an AJAX involved in your load. I do appreciate you time!!

Answer (score 8):

All the current solutions are just treating symptoms of the main problem. If you want your handler to execute *after* all your ajax loads, then you may use a promise.

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax();
var ajax2 = $.ajax();

jQuery(function($) {
    $.when.apply($, [ajax1, ajax2]).done(function() {
        // your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: The other answers don't take any AJAX stuff into consideration. The AJAX requests may or may not be done by the time `window.onload` fires. This is the right answer. I'd upvote but I have no more votes left :(

Comment: Thank you, this works extremely well. Is there anyway to actually get this to happen even faster? I needed to replace text within a div that was being dynamically loaded, it works, there is just a small delay.

Answer (score 3):

Try on the window load event :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //Stuff here
});
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference - the problem is with AJAX loading the content.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure, Try window `load`

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    mark_active_menu();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference - the problem is with AJAX loading the content.

Answer (score 0):

Before(sometimes, doesn't load absolutely at the beginning, a few milliseconds after(0-200ms about)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').hide(0);
});
```

After:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('body').delay(500).show(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation of work with AJAX and HTML. I have the same problem with functions $(document).ready() and $(window).load(). I solved this problem by adding handler of my event (that should work at HTML DOC), to the jQuery function that runs right after AJAX reguest was finished. Read this: ["
jQuery.post()"](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (third parameter in the function).

In my code it looks like this:

```
var RequestRootFolderContent = function(){
    $.post(
        'PHP/IncludeFiles/FolderContent.inc.php',
        function(data){
            $('[class~="folder-content"]').html(data);

            //Here what you need
            $('[class~="file"]').dblclick(function(){
                alert("Double click");
            });
        }
    )
}
```